# Breaking a large array into several meaningful variables in Matlab for ODE solvers

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, organization

I am trying improve the way I simulate dynamical system with Matlab/Octave ode solvers, more specifically the way I split the main array of variables into smaller and more meaningful/readable variables.

My standard way of implementing the odefun called by ode45 is as  follows (a simple example):

```
function d_states=model_as_I_usually_do(t,states)

% 1- parameter definition
m=1;
k=2;


% 2- index definition
pos_i=1:3; %position
vel_i=pos_i(end)+(1:3); %velocity

% 3- extracting data from states vector
pos=states(pos_i);
vel=states(vel_i);

% 4- even more specific renaming for convenince
x=pos(1);y=pos(2);z=pos(3);
u=vel(1);v=vel(2);w=vel(3);

% 5- dynamics
F=[1,1,1]';
a=F/m-k/m*[x y^2 z^3]'; %some equations

% 6- filling output (derivative) vector
d_states(pos_i)=vel;
d_states(vel_i)=a;

end
```

It has helped me a lot before, but steps 2, 3 and 6 (and to some extent 4 ) become hard and repetitive to manage as the complexity of the problem grows (60+ states).

More specifically, whenever I add a new variable I spread information in 3 or 4 places. I could bundle steps 2,3 and 4 together for each variable instead, which is an improvement because then the information would be in 2 places ( the beginning and the end). Still, my goal would be having it all in 1 place and not having to worry explicitly about indexing

The following is a pseudo code of what I had in mind, where I try to follow a more object-oriented approach:

```
%%( some place before the call to the ode solver)
% new position representation
newstate.name="pos"
newstate.size=3;
newstate.alt_names={"x","y","z"}; % or alternatively, nothing
newstate.derivative="vel";
state_organizer.add(newstate);

% new velocity representation
newstate.name="vel";
newstate.size=3;
newstate.alt_names={"u","v","w"};
newstate.derivative="a";
state_organizer.add(newstate);


function d_states=model_I_would_prefer(t,states,state_organizer)
% 1- parameter definition (the same as before)

% does 2,3 and (possibly)4 without having to worry about indexes
state_organizer.extract(states);

% 5- dynamics ( the same as before)

% does the same as 6
state_organizer.update_derivatives(d_states);
end
```

In a language with pointers, it would be straightforward to do. Something that could look like this:

```
% encoding the velocity state
newstate.variable_ptr=&vel;
newstate.derivative_ptr=&a
...
% extracting from the main state array ( states)
for each state in state_organizer
  *(state.variable_ptr)=states(state.index)
end
...
% transferring to array d_states
for each state in state_organizer
  d_states(state.index)=*(state.derivative_ptr)
end
```

Matlab does not have pointers ( [it has handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5),but then every variable would need to be inside an object). One alternative would be to use the function "eval", [not a good one](http://www.matlabtips.com/how-to-point-at-in-matlab/), but it would look like this:

```
% adding a state ( vel)
organizer.state(n).index=organizer.last_index+(1:size);
organizer.state(n).derivative='a';
organizer.state(n).name='vel';
organizer.last_index=organizer.last_index+size;
...
% step 6 ( similar in essence to step 2)
for each state in organizer 
   eval(['d_states(' organizer.state(k).index ')=' organizer.state(k).derivative ';'])
end
```

With that and my goal ( information for each state in one place, automatic indexing)  in mind, my main questions are:

1. Is there a way to implement something similar in Matlab/Octave? ( Not considering Simulink).
2. Is there an alternate approach to do it that would be better (either more organized or more doable)? For example, using dictionaries or automatically generating a M-file.
3. Same as 1 and 2, but considering other languages or resources, such as python (I was considering switching to it already) or C++.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly then the problem are the hard coded numbers 1, 2, and 3 in steps 2 and 4. Providing them as inputs in the function would make the function general enough to be recyclable for a larger class of models.

Say:

```
% 2- index definition
pos_i=1:n_pos; %position, or pos_i=1:nx+ny+nz
vel_i=pos_i(end)+(1:n_pos); %velocity

% 4- even more specific renaming for convenince
x=pos(1:nx);y=pos(1+nx:nx+ny);z=pos(1+nx+ny:nx+ny+nz);
u=vel(1:nu);v=vel(1+nu:nu+nv);w=vel(1+nu+nv:nu+nv+nw);
```

You can also wrap `nx, ny, nz` in an array (the same for velocities), say `pos_ind` then

```
n_pos = numel(pos_ind);
nx = pos_ind(1);
ny = pos_ind(2);
nz = pos_ind(3);
```

Then all you need to do is to define `pos_ind` and `vel_ind` before you call your function and add them as inputs. You can tune as appropriate for your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this is not my main issue. Those hard coded numbers are usually very specific, small and immutable ( e.g. 3DOF for a velocity vector). I will make and edit to try and make it more clear, I am sorry if I was confusing.